# Error when trying to upload data from csv to mysql database using python

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7, csv

```
def ICP():
    path = r'C:/Users/Desktop/ICP'
    allFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.csv"))
    frame = pd.DataFrame()
    list_ = []
    for file_ in allFiles:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=False, header=2, skipfooter = 2, engine = 'python', sep=",", quotechar = "'")
        list_.append(df)
    frame = pd.concat(list_, ignore_index=True)
    # print (frame)
    # print (frame.columns)
    engine = engineconnect()
    con = engine.connect()
    frame.to_sql(con=engine, name='ICP', if_exists = 'replace')
```

I have written this function to read the data from csv and upload it the sql database. But I am getting this error.
(1059, "Identifier name 'Label\tType\tDate Time\tElement\tElement Label\tFlags\tUnadjusted Data\tConcentration\tUnit\tIntensity\tConcen' is too long")

How to solve this? Thanks!!

Comment: Your label name is too long for the field in MySQL. You can either increase the size of the field, or preferably, trim the length of the label before it gets submitted.

Comment: Thanks for your response.can you please show me clearly how to do this? I am very new to python and no idea how to do that.